# Configuration file in Visual studio database project

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

When I am deploying my database project. I have to create a column in table based on some config value.

For example I have three columns Student Id , Dept Id, Joining Date.

In one instance of deployment I need all three but in another instance I need only Student Id and Joining Date.

I have one approach where I will have some existing Boolean table from which I will read and if bit is one I will create Dept Id column otherwise not.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: It's better to have 2 baranches from one core project in your version controll system. One branch for each deploying case.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to create duplicate codes.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to separate  projects than create new difficult configs